# Why does no-wrap width calculation change when it is nested inside of an element with a display of table?

Tags: css

With our design we end up needing multiple columns to display titles with ellipsis which I don't expect to be a big deal but when they are nested inside of a `display: table` the calculations seem to be incorrect.

The caveats are that we want a responsive layout so percentage widths are required (fixed widths would solve the problem).  And our layouts do require a `display: table` much further up the tree and I can't removing it without a major refactor.

If you remove the display everything works as I would expect:

[EXPECTED](http://cssdesk.com/gtsKp)

But having that display causes the parent to take into account the child elements total width pre-truncated (but with nowrap taken into account).  It is as if the initial rendering happens without an overflow being defined and adds it after the fact (but by that point the width calculation is way too large).

[RESULT](http://cssdesk.com/4gmJN)

I can guess at why the rendering is breaking but I would like a more definitive answer about how the browser renders this... (Tested in Chrome/FF/Safari on Mac)

Comment: This is a little bit messy, you are nesting a block element (ul) inside an inline element (span) and using display table directly inside something display table cell (non standard, so the final browser rendering becomes unpredictable), without using table-row... Could you explain what you really need?

Comment: The example above is not related to my code; I just used a bunch of elements to demonstrate the behavior I am seeing (instead of defining a hand full of classes).  `display: table` was added originally so multiple columns would end having the same dynamic height (no js).  Anyway what I want is to understand is why we have this behavior around nowrap (I am not looking for a "how to make html look like my screen-shot", I can do that).  Also I would not expect table-row to effect my example because I don't think it would effect the width calculations (but it was a little sloppy to leave out).

Comment: It does behave the same in all browsers, so I do think it is an anticipatable behavior (and an expected pattern).  My guess is that I just don't know enough about the lower level paint/layout cycles of the browser to understand the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this has got to do with the way tables layout cells when using the `auto` layout method.

The details of how it works are explained in [section 17 of the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout), but the key point is that the `auto` layout depends on the contents of the cell (which is why it's so big when you force your content onto one line), whereas the `fixed` layout is only dependent on the table width (which is what you're expecting).

If you just add `table-layout:fixed` to your .table selector, your problem should be solved.

Comment: Just read the spec and you summed it up pretty nicely; that absolutely answered my question.